# Anyway to fill space on a chart area using flex dashboard? Two outputs per chart area?

Tags: html, r, shiny, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I've been struggling with this for a while and pretty much I want see if there is a way I can have a combined output. I'm using flexdashboard to make a dashboard and I really want to have a tab feature where I can put various monthly datasets. Unfortunately when I use .tabset I can only have one chart area per column.

Here is where I am at with my dashboard.

[image]

The problem is all that empty space below. I can't add another chart area using ### because it will just add it to the tabset.

I was wondering if there was a way to make two objects output in the area (above and below) or maybe its possible to attach a graph below it?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. I've already tried using tabBox and tabsetPabels but it doens;t work properly so I'm stuck with this format.

Desired output:

[image]

Code:

````
---
title: "Example Demo Dash"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny 
---


# Tab 1

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(readr)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(rsconnect)
require(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
require(plotly)
```

Column 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Tab 1 Graph

# Tab 2

Column {data-width=450, .tabset}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------



```{r}


cars <- datatable(head(mtcars,10),
          rownames = FALSE,
          options = list(
            dom = 't',
            paging = FALSE,
            info = FALSE,
            scrollY = FALSE,
            sort = FALSE
            
      )
) 


iriss <- datatable(head(iris,10),
          rownames = FALSE,
          options = list(
            dom = 't',
            paging = FALSE,
            info = FALSE,
            scrollY = FALSE,
            sort = FALSE
            
      )
) 

```

### Cars Tab 1  

```{r}
cars
```


### Iris Tab 2
```{r}
iriss
```




Column {data-width=200}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Tab 2 Col 2 Graph 1

### Tab 2 Col 2 Graph 1

### Tab 2 Col 2 Graph 3

### Tab 2 Col 2 Graph 3

Column {data-width=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
### Col 3 graph 1

### Col 3 graph 2

# tab 3
````